# delete pointers created by new in CallBack Function

Tags: c++

I am doing the following:

```
LRESURT CALLBACK WindowProc{
    .......
    Case VK_RETURN:
        int i;
        for ( i = 0; i <1000; i++) {
            int  size = determinesize(i);
            int *pttest = new int[size];
            .....(some work)....
            delete[] pttest;
        }
     ........
}
```

But I got problem when `VK_RETURN` occurs. If I don't use `delete[] pttest`.

My question is that: Do I need to delete ptttest? When I search on google, almost everyone said that for each new, there must be a delete. Another question is that: if I put the for loop code for `VK_RETURN` in a function, say `void whenvkreturn()`, then do I need to delete pttest? Since any local variables are destroyed after returning, I guess the 1000 objects created in this loop will be deleted automatically, right? I don't know the stack very well, so some explanation I found is not clear for me.

=====

OK, there is a vector workaround. But when it is the case:

`TCHAR *text = new text[size];`

What I am supposed to do?

Comment: Yes, you **always** need any heap allocated memory. It doesn't matter WHERE you do the allocation. Only stack allocated variables are automatically deleted.

Comment: The `new` operator allocates memory on the heap, so you have to **manually** release those memory allocated. By the way, your code in the loop is not exception safe, there're cases that you might have a leak in the loop. Use `std::vector` to avoid any possible problems.

Comment: i am wondering if you might benefit from putting `int *pttest = new int[size];` in front of your loop and `delete[] pttest;` after the end of the loop. It seems you just need it to hold some variables during computation. But be careful about the initialization of it.

Comment: Use `std::string` instead of `new char[size]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always need to delete allocated memory. For every **new** there should be a **delete**, even though it is in a function. The problem you are approaching, can easily be solved by using other containers with dynamic sizes, like std::vector. Using dynamic containers in local functions, it will automatically release the memory allocated by itself, and you don't have to worry.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your question, yes, you need to delete `pttest`, unless you want to intentionally leak memory. Basically, whenever you're allocating something with `new`/`new[]`, you're supposed to `delete`/`delete[]` it manually later when you don't need it anymore.

But you really should consider using `std::vector` instead of an array allocated with `new[]`. You won't then have to worry about freeing the memory with `delete[]`, `std::vector` will do that automatically in its destructor.

Answer (score 1):

If you leave the code as it is then you don't need to use delete, or new for that matter:

```
int size = determinesize(i);
std::vector<int> test( size );
.....(some work)....
```

a stack based solution will work just as well. If you want to leave it as it is then of course you don't *need* to delete `pttest` at this point but you'll have to delete it at some point and taking it out of the switch increases the risk that it won't work correctly and will lean.

Comment: @Fanael I've changed that. Probably should have done this in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a pointer using new or new[] operations in C++ you allocate memory in the heap. This is the case even if you do this in a method. So you need to use delete or delete[] as appropriate in order to deallocate the heap memory.

Answer (score 1):

As a rule you should never use new[] these days and certainly not delete. Instead use vector.
For extra efficiency points reuse the same vector resize it tto avoid allocating 1000 separate arrays:

```
vector<int> test;

for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
    test.resize(determinsize(i));
    ...
}
```