# compare typed string in a combobox with its items

Tags: c++, string, combobox, std

Suppose I have 20 string of different length, each of them is supposed to obtained similar to the following:

```
TCHAR *itemText[...];
SendMessage(hwndCombobox, CB_GETLBTEXT, i, (LPARAM)itemText);
```

Since I have an index for the items, I would like to use the above code in a for loop.
But because each item has different length, I can't use something like:

```
int itemLength = SendMessage(hwndCombobox, CB_GETLBTEXTLEN, i, 0);
TCHAR *itemText[itemLength];
```

Since using the message `CB_GETLBTEXTLEN` require the length at first, it is necessary to get the length. I know I can just use, for example, `TCHAR *itemText[1024];`, but I don't like this way personally.

I also tried to use `new` and `delete`, and other people suggest me to use `vector` along with `std::string` instead, as in this post [delete pointers created by new in CallBack Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10653746/delete-pointers-created-by-new-in-callback-function), but that leads to another problem in that the LPARAM parameter needed for `CB_GETLBTEXT` requires `A pointer to the buffer that receives the string.`, so the following code doesn't work, since the last parameter is `std::string`, rather than a pointer which receives strings:

```
int i;
Vec<std::string> itemText;
for (i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
    ......... // Don't know how to initialize a string with a specified length.
    SendMessage(win->hwndFindBox, CB_GETLBTEXT, i, (LPARAM)itemText.At(i));
}
```

I don't neither know how to initialize a `std::string str` with a specified length.

In fact, I would like to compare the typed string in the edit control of a combobox control with the items on this combobox. Do you have any suggestion to solve this problem or to do what I want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have misunderstood suggestions to use `std::vector` with `std::string`.  You should use `std::vector<TCHAR>` as a temporary buffer when reading the ComboBox item text (because you cannot write directly to the internal buffer used by `std::basic_string`), and then you can copy that into a `std::basic_string<TCHAR>` afterward if desired:

```
std::basic_string<TCHAR> s;
int itemLength = SendMessage(hwndCombobox, CB_GETLBTEXTLEN, i, 0);
if (itemLength != CB_ERR)
{
    std::vector<TCHAR> buf(itemLength + 1 /* for NUL */);
    SendMessage(hwndCombobox, CB_GETLBTEXT, i, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&buf[0]));

    s = &buf[0];
}
```

This works because `std::vector` is guaranteed to use contiguous memory, so `&buf[0]` should be equivalent to an array (assuming that `buf` is not empty, but in this case, we guarantee that it has at least 1 element).